# Error when installing NuGet package 'Facebook 6.1.2' Windows 8 App

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, nuget, windows-store-apps

When trying to install the Facebook 6.1.2 NuGet into my Windows 8 application I get the following message:

```
PM> Install-Package Facebook
Successfully installed 'Facebook 6.1.2'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Facebook 6.1.2'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Facebook 6.1.2'. You are trying to install
this package into a project that targets '.NETCore,Version=v4.5', but the package does not
contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more
information, contact the package author.
```

Is there anyway to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Details at https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/issues/199

TLDR;

we now store the facebook.dll for win store apps in `win8` folder rather than `winRT45` which is only understood by nuget 2.1+. So make sure your nuget package manager is up to date.

Comment: Perfect, updated my nuget and it worked first time. thanks for the fast response.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the Facebook 6.1.2 package is not targeted to version 4.5 of the .Net framework.

Try targetting version 4.0 in you're Windows 8 App project.

Comment: When i go into the properties the drop down box for changing the .Net version is greyed out and empty.